# Что означают ключи openssl в этой фразе?

Tags: openssl

При шифровании файла  OpenSSL с ключем -salt  выдает сообщение : WARNING : deprecated key derivation used. Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.

Хотелось бы знать точное значение этих ключей.

Comment: `-salt` = ключ\параметр\... =) для чего какой нужен можно ознакомится в документации по OpenSSL или прочитав краткую справку по параметрам `OpenSSL -help`

Comment: что делает  -salt я знаю, меня интересуют ключи  -iter и -pbkdf2. Хотя про -pbkdf2 я нашел информацию :)

Comment: -help(--help\-h\-?) пробуйте, будет вам краткая справка по всем ключам